# DropDownList asp.net C# MVC error con type or namespace

Tags: asp.net, dropdownlist

Me han pedido crear una calculadora en asp.net utilizando MVC y me he puesto manos a la obra, pero, he encontrado un contratiempo con el dropdownlistfor y segun la informacion que he recopilado todo esta bien T_T

Este  es el codigo mi controlador

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using practica3.Models;


namespace practica3.Controllers
{

public class HomeController : Controller 
{
     public ActionResult Calculadora(CalculadoraModel model)
    {
        ModelState.Clear();
        switch (model.Operacion)
        {
            case CalculadoraOperador.Suma:
                model.Result = model.FirstNumber + model.SecondNumber;
                break;
            case CalculadoraOperador.Resta:
                model.Result = model.FirstNumber - model.SecondNumber;
                break;
            case CalculadoraOperador.Multiplicacion:
                model.Result = model.FirstNumber * model.SecondNumber;
                break;
            case CalculadoraOperador.Division:
                model.Result = model.FirstNumber / model.SecondNumber;
                break;
        }
        return View(model);


    }
```

Este es mi modelo

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel;

namespace practica3.Models
{
 public class CalculadoraModel
    {
        public decimal FirstNumber { get; set; }
        public decimal SecondNumber { get; set; }
        public decimal Result { get; set; }
        public CalculadoraOperador Operacion { get; set; }


    }

    public enum CalculadoraOperador
    {
    Suma = '+',
    Resta = '-',
    Multiplicacion = '*',
    Division = '/'

}


}
```

Esta es mi vista

```
 @model practica3.Models.CalculadoraModel


@{
ViewBag.Title = "Calculadora";
}


<h2>Calculadora</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm("Calculadora", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
@Html.LabelFor(m => m.FirstNumber) @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.FirstNumber)<br />
@Html.LabelFor(m => m.SecondNumber) @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.SecondNumber)<br />
@Html.LabelFor(m => m.Result) @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Result)<br />

@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Operacion, new SelectList(Enum.GetValues(typeof(CalculadoraOperador))), "Seleccionar Operador")
```

Mi problema esta con CalculadoraOperador, el me da un error, pero, segun este link: http://www.tutorialsteacher.com/mvc/htmlhelper-dropdownlist-dropdownlistfor
Segun pude entender la cosa va asi: tengo una clase x con sus propiedades y sus metodos get y set, luego tengo que tener otra clase de la forma public enum z con los nombres de los items que quiero en mi dropDownList.
Entonces una de las propiedades de x la escribo asi: public z operador { get; set; }

Entonces ya en mi vista solo deberia escribir el siguiente codigo y todo funcionaria correctamente

```
 @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.operador, 
                new SelectList(Enum.GetValues(typeof(z))), 
                "seleciona una operacion")
```

En donde m.operador es la propiedad tipo z y z es clase tipo public enum, pero, me da error cuando le pongo la z

```
<input type="submit" />
}
```

Muchas gracias por sus respuestas

Comment: No entendí mucho eso de la **propiedad Z**.. pero que error es el que te lanza?

Comment: Muchas gracias por la preocupacion, pero, me han ayudado en la uni. Lo que me faltaba era poner algo asi @using NombreProyecto.Models  en la vista y con eso se resolvio el problema..., muchas gracias nuevamente

Comment: @BarlyEspinal agrega la respuesta completa y márcala como aceptada, de este modo ayudas a mantener la buena salud del sitio (% de preguntas con respuesta aceptada)

Comment: No entiendo como puedo hacer eso en este post, me podrias ayudar por favor